# Which technology to choose for PubSub between java service and C# client

Tags: c#, java, comet, publish-subscribe, cometd.net

Which technology would you suggest for PubSub between Java Service and C# desktop client.
What do you think about CometD? Is there any nice .net API for it?
Server and client will run within the same organization so can use different protocols 
Is CometD a right choice at all or would it be better to use TCP instead of HTTP?

Comment: Have a look at Oracle's Coherence. it was orginially return for Java but also have a port for .net C#

Answer (score 0):

Since your apps run within the same organization, you will likely be able to use more efficient transport than HTTP, or even TCP, depending on your situation and requirements.

The Data Distribution Service (DDS) is a standard by the OMG based on Pub/Sub. Standardized language bindings are C, C++, Java and Ada, but C# and others are available as well. Different languages as well as operating systems can be mixed in your system. Structured datatypes to be distributed are specified in a language-neutral format (by the standard a subset of OMG IDL), which is then translated into language-specific interfaces and datatypes to be used by your applications.

It can use different transport layers, like UDP or also TCP. Although I can not determine from your brief description whether DDS would be your best choice, I think it is worth investigating. See [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_distribution_service) for a very brief introduction and list of references.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I have only used cometd (no atmosphere or even none-java solutions)

I like cometd as it was very fast to get started and the documentation was good. Also the javascript API worked without any issues.

and then the bayeux specification could be implemented on c# too: https://github.com/Oyatel/CometD.NET

http://bugs.cometd.org/browse/COMETD-23

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at some messaging protocols such as [AMQP](http://amqp.org/) and [STOMP](http://stomp.github.io/). There's decent support for both protocols in both Java and .NET and you can choose your choice of message brokers such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ and others.